# Multiple indexer for single index in Azure Search?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have two data source one in MS SQL and one is Azure Table, both of them holds User's data but just different information.

Is there any risk or possible issues if I create two indexer for each of the data source and sync them into single index, so I can do one search instead of two.

I do not see option that allow me to create indexer only, so I wonder if Microsoft trying to prevent that or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have more than one indexer updating the same index, races between updates to the same document are possible since Azure Search does not yet support document versioning. 
If the each indexer updates different document fields, then the order doesn't matter; if multiple indexers update the same field(s), then the last writer wins (and you can't control which indexer will be the last writer).

If you use a deletion detection policy to remove documents from the index, then, to avoid possible races, a document should be marked deleted in both SQL and Azure Table.

> I do not see option that allow me to create indexer only, so I wonder if Microsoft trying to prevent that or not.

I don't understand the above question.

Comment: Current in Azure portal, I don't find any button/option that allow me only to create a indexer, I always have to do Import Data, select data source, forced to create a new indexer, then forced to a new index.  That's the only way I can I can find to create a new indexer.

Comment: Right, currently Portal has a limitation and doesn't let you create an indexer targeting an existing index. You will need to create such an indexer programmatically using client SDK or REST API.